# Incorrect crossdomain.xml file contents from api.soundcloud.com

Tags: actionscript-3, api, soundcloud

It seems there is something wrong with SoundCloud.com's **[crossdomain.xml](https://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml)** file at this URL:
https://api.soundcloud.com/crossdomain.xml

If you open that xml link in a new tab/window and refresh the page a few times you will notice the inconsistency of shown xml content...

**It sometimes serves this:**

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <!--
        Allow access from anywhere. This policy should be used for domains
        serving third party apps (api, images, streams).
    -->
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**But also it sometimes serves this instead:**

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <!--
        Lock down access to Flash applications served by us.
        This policy should be served for all domains that Flash apps require
        access to and that are not serving api, images or stream (those need
        to be open to third party apps as well).
    -->
    <allow-access-from domain="soundcloud.com" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.soundcloud.com" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.sndcdn.com" secure="false"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

We need the **first response** (Allow-All) to be always served for our SoundCloud integration to work (embeded soundcloud tracks in Calameo publications: http://www.calameo.com)

Any ideas to fix or work around this? Thanks.

**UPDATE (2015/10/12)**

It seems SoundCloud changed their crossdomain.xml file for the incorrect version instead of the correct one. The URL now serves only:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <!--
        Lock down access to Flash applications served by us.
        This policy should be served for all domains that Flash apps require
        access to and that are not serving api, images or stream (those need
        to be open to third party apps as well).
    -->
    <allow-access-from domain="soundcloud.com" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.soundcloud.com" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.sndcdn.com" secure="false"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Well, uhm, is this a question or a feedback to SoundCloud developers? This site is for Q-A only..

Comment: I'm also confused, how did arrive at the conclusion that SO is in any shape or form affiliated or responsible for SoundClouds stuff? [Have you considered sending SoundCloud an e-Mail?](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

Comment: I emailed Soundcloud support and here is what they responded: If after following the suggestions above you are still seeking support on using SoundCloud’s API please get back in touch with a link to a Stackoverflow post about your question and we can follow up with a member of our engineering team and ask them to respond to you there.

Comment: Instead of asking **them** to change their server settings, why dont you ask here about **your own app**? What is this Calameo app doing that cant be done like this **[API Example](https://p1.soundcloud.com/player.swf?enable_api=true&object_id=myPlayer&referer=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fdjblesone%2Fbreaks-to-go)**... Show us a link to your player and ask for help with that

Comment: I'm not asking them to change their server settings. I'm just asking them to fix the inconsistent response of their crossdomain.xml file. Please read my post carefully, you'll see what i'm talking about (also check the comment in the xml response and you'll see that something is clearly wrong on their end).

Comment: Point taken and I apologise. I will edit your question if thats okay...

Comment: Great work @VC.One - will approve that edit! :) This now looks more like a question, rather than just stating something is wrong.

Comment: We have the same issue. After refreshing 7 times in the browser I actually got the *correct* crossdomain.xml file. We can not load the sound file in our application.